# How do you handle multiple AJAX requests in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, http, scripting, webserver

My AJAX search program keeps asking PHP for results of a particular search term. The start of the PHP script reads thru a MySQL DB and initializes, so if the PHP keeps restarting, it will have to read the DB millions of times. If I can keep it alive and let multiple silly AJAX requests be served by a single running PHP script instance I'm sure performance would improve.

How do you do this typically? Use a service? Can this be done with services?

Comment: is this for a tagging system? No way you could parse once the text for keywords and have the found keywords turned into link once and for all? Maybe explain what you intend to do exactly.

Comment: Basically I have one PHP script that the AJAX request is supposed to query. I'm not sure how I'm going to do the AJAX part but I'm trying to understand the PHP side first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing the db results in a session variable? You'd check first if the keyword is not in the session (sessions allow to transport variable values between page refreshes), and if not, do a db query.

To store it:

```
$_SESSION['storedQueries']['keyword']= 'its definition, from the database';
```

To look for it:

```
  $index=  array_search('keyword',array_keys($_SESSION['storedQueries']));
  $result = ($index) ? $_SESSION['storedQueries'][$index] : 'nothing found, you should do a db query';
```

The ajax part is pretty easy if you use a javascript library, such as jquery:

```
$('#resultZone').load('find.php',{keyword: $('input.search').val() });
```

Comment: Are session variables sent on HTTP?

Comment: from the doc: " A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL. "

Answer (score 2):

PHP has no concept of long-lived objects or shared state between threads or requests, every request always starts at zero (except for the session state, of course). You can emulate long-lived objects by caching to disk or memory (see [memcached](http://www.danga.com/memcached/)).

Do you have a particular reason to read the entire database when your script initializes?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the results are the same every time, just move those results to a session variable.

PHP sessions are explained pretty well in their documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 1):

If the search result is something that would be similar to multiple users, I usually create a cache file and serialize the result set there. As a filename I might use md5sum of a string containing the search query and perhaps user group. Then when a Ajax needs the data I just need to check if the file is too old, if not I just need to send it to the client or maybe even just redirect the Ajax http-request to the file (assuming it is formatted properly). If the file is too old, I just refresh it with new content.

For very high volume sites memcached is usually a better option. And also some kind of php cache helps and SQL connection pooling lowers the overhead of opening SQL connections.

Answer (score 0):

connecting to the DB is a very expensive operation and you can go around that by caching the results, take a look at [Zend_Cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.html) and see how it can save you allot headache.